# Dynamically add empty index to array based on default indexes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have below array, which includes a set of default indexes, that must be present in my final array:

```
'entities' => [
        'deliveredAt',
        'issuedAt',
        'totals' => [
            'due',
            'gross',
            'net',
            'tax' => [
                'amount',
                'net',
                'rate',
            ],
        ]
],
```

The above array is saved in a variable called `$entities`.

Now, I have a 3rd party API, that will return the above entities, but only include them in the response if the entity contains a value.

For example, a `$response` can look like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "issuedAt" => "2020-08-20"
  "totals" => array:1 [▼
    "tax" => []
  ]
]
```

As you can see, if comparing the returned array with the indexes that I expect, there is a few missing:

- `deliveredAt`
- `totals.due`, `totals.gross`, `totals.net`, `totals.tax.amount`, `totals.tax.net`, `totals.tax.rate`

I am trying to make a method that can iterate over the `$response` array, and check if it contains the indexes that I expect. If not, I simply want to set the index with a value of `null`.

Below is what I have so far:

```php
foreach ($entities as $key => $entity) {
         if (!is_array($entity)) {
             if (!isset($response[$entity])) {
                    $response[$entity] = null;
             }
         }
}
```

However, this will only add an index that is not an array. In this example, it will only add: `deliveredAt => null`.

How can I do, so the above method can iterate through multiple at least 2 nested arrays and add the index name and `null` value?

Comment: And if no `tax` provided - should it be `tax => null`, or `tax => [amount => null etc ]`?

Comment: @u_mulder it should be `tax => ['amount' => null, 'net' => null, 'rate' => null]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define initial array with keys and `NULL` (or whatever you need) as values:

```
$entities = [
    'deliveredAt' => null,
    'issuedAt' => null,
    'totals' => [
        'due' => null,
        'gross' => null,
        'net' => null,
        'tax' => [
            'amount' => null,
            'net' => null,
            'rate' => null,
        ],
    ]
];

// here's your real data
$realData = [
  "issuedAt" => "2020-08-20",
  "totals" => [
    "tax" => [
      'net' => 42,    
    ]
  ]
];
// now use array_replace_recursive to replace keys in `$entities` with values of `$realData`
print_r(array_replace_recursive($entities, $realData));
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/S09e5).

Also note that keys from `$realData` that do not exist in `$entities` will be added to result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_replace_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-replace-recursive.php) for doing this. You had only to change your associative array entities a little bit, so every property needs a initiliasation (e.g. NULL or '').

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($entities, $array);
```

Here you can test it http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4688ed3240050479edeef7c9e4da16f98dbe01de

Here is the hole code:

```
$array = [
  "issuedAt" => "2020-08-20",
  "totals" => [
    "tax" => [
        'amount' => 100
    ]
  ]
];

$entities = [
    'deliveredAt' => NULL,
    'issuedAt' => NULL,
    'totals' => [
        'due' => NULL,
        'gross' => NULL,
        'net' => NULL,
        'tax' => [
            'amount' => NULL,
            'net' => NULL,
            'rate' => NULL
        ],
    ]
];

$result = array_replace_recursive($entities, $array);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: And what's the difference with my answer?

Comment: You are right. I was in the meantime 1 hour away and didn't saw your answer as I completed my answer and posted it. Give you 1 point.